# UICollectionView XCode Custom cell

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I created a custom class for super UICollectionViewCell. Now when I call

```
MyCollectionViewCell *itemView = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

I get a warning:

> "Pointers types do not match",(cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] returns UICollectionView cell ).

How do I fix it?

Comment: What is the base class for MyCollectionViewCell? It should be a UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: In which function you are calling above method??

Answer (score 4):

The warning is because cellForItemAtIndexPath returns a UICollecitonViewCell.  you have to cast it as a MyCollectionViewCell such as:

```
MyCollectionViewCell *itemView = (MyCollectionViewCell*)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This should take care of the warning.

Comment: Very true. If you are using custom cells then to make it work fine, casting is important.